# Javascript not working properly on Firefox on URL

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to use this simple code:

> javascript:document.getElementsByName("tabla-usuarios_length")[0].options[3].text="10000";

I tested it on Chrome(URL) and it works perfectly, also in both Firefox and Google Chrome's Console.

In both console's it works and it gives me like a message "10000" in the console.[image: Here it works perfectly]

In Firefox URL, it redirects like to a blank page with that same message instead of just working on the page I am. so since it goes to that blank page I can't see the results and to come back to the page I was I have to tap on back and of course it reloads losing the possible change that I made with the JS code.. 
[image: Here it redirects to a blank space with that text..]

I really need it working with the url stuff since I need to use it with iMacros (URL GOTO=javascript:....) so I can't use it with Console.

Thanks I hope I explained myself correctly.

Comment: Ensure `javascript:` is prepended to the url when you copy paste it to the url bar. The `javascript:` part tends to go away (for security reason)

Comment: Bookmarklets are so quaint - wrap the code in IIFE if you really must do this in firefox ... or add `,undefined` before the `;` - if the "result" of your bookmarklet is undefined, firefox plays nicely

Comment: I just added 2 screenshots, I am doing the javascript: right I guess. I have also tried Bookmarklets and it's the same result.

Comment: I have tried commands like alert("hello") and it works on the url so I'm confused.

Comment: firefox is "sensitive" to the return value of the script in the address bar - see answer below

Comment: `alert("hello")` return value is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three alternatives

wrap a simple command in `void()`

```
javascript:void(document.getElementsByName("tabla-usuarios_length")[0].options[3].text="10000");
```

or - use IIFE

```
javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByName("tabla-usuarios_length")[0].options[3].text="10000";})();
```

or, again only with simple command, use `,` operator like so:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName("tabla-usuarios_length")[0].options[3].text="10000",undefined;
```

Seems Firefox looks at the return value of bookmarklets. If it is `udefined` it works as expected

> All complex bookmarklets **I've** ever seen were always wrapped in IIFE - which is why they've always worked

Even the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) page (which I only now read) shows this requirement - with one other format for them

```
javascript:{arbitrary script};void(0);
```

Comment: There's a fourth now :p

Comment: IIFE ... simple form is `(function() { ... your code goes here ... for bookmarklets there should be NO RETURN statement })();` - Immediately Invoked Function Expression